# Proof of triple product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Consider [this](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Eercelebi/Ax(BxC).pdf) proof of the triple product identity. In this proof, they state that $\lambda $ does not depened on any choice of three vectors $A,B,C$. I don't understand why is that true? I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Quick answer: Use trilinearity of the triple cross product.  See [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926600)

Comment: @user10354138 what is exactly trilinearity ?

Comment: linear in the three variables $A$, $B$, $C$ separately.

Comment: @user10354138 what you mean is that $(A_1+A_2)\times B\times C =  A_1\times B\times C+A_2\times B\times C$, and also for $B,C$ as well